# In facebook PHP API, how can I get the ID information return by facook when I have updated a photo to facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-graph-api

In PHP, using what command I can fetch the id information returned by the facebook when I have upload a new photo to the album.

Answer (score 3):

When you upload a photo using Graph API you have the id right in response.